MaxDOP setting for SQL Server 2022 on a machine with Dual Xeon processors
What would be the recommended MaxDOP when installing SQL Server 2022 on a machine with dual Xeon E5-2683v4 CPUs, i.e. 2 x 16 cores (or 2 x 32 logical processors) ?  This machine has 128GB of ECC RAM.
By default, SQL Server 2022 sets it to 8, but I'm worried it won't be using the dual Xeon configuration to its full potential.

The recommendation would vary with the characteristics of your workload about which we know nothing
